# Can't resolve Fatal Error on our Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function str_contains() in /services/webpages/util/g/q/gqf34liq.myutilitysite.com/**site removed**/public/wp-includes/load.php:1618
> Stack trace: #0 /services/webpages/util/g/q/gqf34liq.myutilitysite.com/**site removed**/public/wp-includes/default-constants.php(43): wp_convert_hr_to_bytes('256m')
> #1 /servic es/webpages/util/g/q/gqf34liq.myutilitysite.com/**site removed**/public/wp-settings.php(61): wp_initial_constants()
> #2 /services/webpages/util/g/q/gqf34liq.myutilitysite.com/**site removed**/public/wp-config.php(82): require_once('/services/webpa...')
> #3 /services/webpages/util/g/q/gqf34liq.myutilitysite.com/**site removed**/public/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/services/webpa...')
> #4 /services/webpages/util/g/q/gqf34liq.myutilitysite.com/**site removed**/public/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/services/webpa...')
> #5 /services/webpages/util/g/q/gqf34liq.myutilitysite.com/**site removed**/public/wp-admin/index.php in /services/webpages/util/g/q/gqf34liq.myutilitysite.com/**site removed**/public/wp-includes/load.php on line 1618

So our company website went down for no apparent reason today, and after an exhausting perusal of forums I replaced the wp-includes folder. I have the site back up, but can no longer access the wp-admin from a browser. I am now getting this error...

I have been out of coding long enough that I am struggling with backtracing the issue here. Is there someone who can help me decipher where the issue is starting or what I am missing?

Comment: str_contains() is available from PHP 8: check the PHP version installed on your server and / or consider to downgrade your wordpress version

Comment: Updating the PHP version on wordpress can be dangerous because any deprecated code will break your site.

Comment: `I replaced the wp-includes folder.` that's very bad, you changed the core's codebase but I'm pretty sure your DB is not updated to match that

Comment: GrafiCode -- The site is back up, but the backend is not functional. So I can agree with that it was probably not good, but it at least got it back up. We are going to completely rebuild the site soon, so I may just leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use an alternative method to check for substring presence.

You can use '**strpos()**' function to achieve similar functionality. Replace instances of '**str_contains()**' with '**strpos() !== false**'.

Additionally, ensure that your server meets the WordPress minimum PHP version requirement. Make sure your WordPress version is compatible with your PHP version to avoid compatibility issues.